# swidth problrm with bxslider slideWidth

Tags: jquery, css, gallery, bxslider

So I'm using bcSlider.

The problem I'm having is with the width, I've looked around here but whatever Ive tried isn't working.

this is where I am testing: http://sophinabano.co.uk/root/pages/blagh.htm

I want the width to be the size of the images, but when I add `slideWidth: 1000;` to

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({ 
    auto: true, 
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    slideWidth: 1000; 
    });
    });
```

The carousel stops working and all the images separate like bullet points. The annoying thing is, it worked before but I wasn't happy with it because the width was too large for my phone for some unresponsive reason.

Ive tried adding slideWidth to the JS:

```
// CAROUSEL         
minSlides: 1,
maxSlides: 1,
moveSlides: 0,
slideWidth: 1000,
```

and it doesn't do anything, I'm guessing it only affect the carousel if you have more than one image in the slide.

Ive tried giving it a div id `<div id="gallery" width: "100px" align="center">` but that doesn't adjust the width. What did I somehow change or not do right?

Answer (score 0):

I am having problems with width too, but a different problem. I'm only getting the hang of bxSlider and I'm new to jquery so these are only suggestions of things to try.  If you want the photo to be 100% of size why force the slide width?  What happens with the slidewidth left with the original settings.

This is the info on slidewidth bxslider site:

slideWidth
The width of each slide. This setting is required for all horizontal carousels!

default: 0
options: integer

Hopefully this helps.